# Copy Grease pencils strokes from a range of frames to another

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil

I am working on a very simple talking head animation using 2D Grease Pencil in Blender 2.83 LTS.
This is my first attempt at using Blender and its significant learning curve. Following along with various tutorials on the web.

I have spend some time animating an eye blink over a series of frames. I would like to copy those strokes/keyframes to various other places in the animation. I know I can cut and paste strokes from a single frame to another pretty simply. But I have yet to figure out a way to copy strokes from multiple frames to a new location in the animation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling around, one can use the cursor to block select a range of keyframes in the timeline/GreasePencil editor then press Shift-D. Then you can drag the copy of the keyframes to a new location.